# How to browse iPod from terminal

Tags: ipod-touch, terminal

How should I use the terminal to browse and manage my iPod Touch? I mean is there any way to do this just with terminal, not with installing MobileTerminal or something like that, or sshing into the iPod.

Answer (score 3):

Enable disk mode, then in terminal

```
$ cd /Volumes
```

then:

```
$ ls
```

and then `cd` into the directory that's your iPod.
From there, you can use ls and cd to browse your iPod from Terminal.

Comment: The question is about an iPod touch, which doesn't have disk mode. The OP doesn't do a very good job of indicating this, but MobileTerminal and SSH aren't available without iOS, and it is tagged ipod-touch.

Answer (score 2):

The free [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/) makes a drag-and-drop interface GUI interface to the iPod.  From the image below shows a path to the device so, once it's mounted, the terminal should be able to find it there (I don't have an iPod to test this.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the iPod's version. If you have the older iPods with "Disk Mode" then yes, they can be mounted like an external drive, and then you can see the hidden files and folders containing your music library.

If it is an iPod touch, you will need to jailbreak it to achieve this as far as I know.

Comment: it is jailbroken, and is an ipod touch.

Comment: If it has an ssh server on it, it is just ssh root@ipaddress and when it prompts you for a password, it's alpine.

Comment: i know that, but mac mounts ipod somewhere in filesystem, my question is where is the mount location?

Comment: it depends on what application you are using to open it, or the serial COM port you are plugging it into.

Comment: If it is an ipod touch, just connect it to wifi and ssh into it is a lot easier than mounting it via usb.

Comment: What hobs is suggesting is to open Cydia, and install the [OpenSSH](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/openssh) package, then use that to connect to your iPod Touch: [Cydia Provided Instructions](http://cydia.saurik.com/openssh.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @hobs suggest you ssh to the iPod, but you state in your question you do not want to do this. The alternative would be to install `sshfuse` locally, and then use ssh to mount the iPod. You can now just `cd` to it somewhere on your local filesystem.

There are also other add-ons for the jailbroken iPod that will let you mount it locally. Browse the 'highlighted' apps section in Cydia.

Answer (score 0):

[iPhoneDisk](http://code.google.com/p/iphonedisk/) is a free application which will mount an iOS device as if it were a hard drive. You can then use Terminal to access it through /Volumes. iPhoneDisk requires you to install [MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) to work. It will even work with a non-jailbroken iPod, although you won't be able to access the full filesystem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For that and much more I always recommend iExplorer from Macroplant:

http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Perfect tool to do anything you want. At the moment I do not remember whether there is a seven day try and buy license, but until now it is worth every cent of the $35 single license fee...

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question for an iPhone. I'm sure it would also work for an iPod.. the concept is the same, as it's an Apple USB device.

answer: use `ifuse`

https://superuser.com/a/1135668/653172

If you like paying for things.. you could probably checkout [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) like [Garex mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177423).. I don't see the point when I own a Mac, and paid a lot for it. Downloading and using *iExplorer* just made me mad enough to find the right answer.